# SELECT SINGLE vs SELECT UP TO 1 ROW

Tags: abap, opensql

I want to understand that why do we use select up to one row when we have select single and which one is faster, what happened at database level when we write those queries and is there any difference when we use HANA database.

Comment: I consider UP TO 1 ROW just when I need to add an ORDER clause. Not sure about other differences, so I will not put this as an answer.

Comment: This question was asked (at least) a thousand times before, probably the most authentic answer is: https://blogs.sap.com/2015/03/11/selecting-one-line-from-an-database-table/ and a follow up: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/11/select-single-vs-select-up-to-1-rows/

Answer (score 2):

There is no major difference, SELECT SINGLE is a bit faster; and that is more on data transfer to/on the ABAP side, then database.

From the SAP ABAP Documentation at
https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapselect_single.htm

> The results set of SELECT statements with the addition SINGLE matches the set from the addition UP TO 1 ROWS without using the addition ORDER BY.
>
> - If the addition SINGLE is used, it is not necessary to use the statements ENDSELECT, ENDWITH or to import the row into an internal table. Not all additions of the SELECT statement, however, can be used.
> - If the addition UP TO 1 ROWS is used, the statement ENDSELECT or    ENDWITH must be specified or the row must be imported into an internal table. The addition ORDER BY can, however, be specified.
>
> A SELECT statement with the addition SINGLE can be optimized for    reading a single row, which means is generally somewhat faster than when using the addition UP TO 1 ROWS. In practice, however, this difference can usually be ignored. In light of this, the following is 
>   recommended:
>
> - Use of the addition SINGLE to read a row specified in full precisely.
> - Use of the addition UP TO 1 ROWS to read a maximum of one row from a set of selected rows.